# Theorem numbering with sub-theorems issue

Tags: numbering, miktex, texlive, theorems

I have a small project for my mathematics degree and have run up against a small problem. I want to have nested levels of theorems/definitions, for instance in the following code it should produce Definition 2.1 to 2.5 then 2.5.1 for the sub-definition. Below is an edited, for brevity, section of my tex file; nothing of importance has been changed.

```
\section{Affine Systems} %section 2 of the document
\newtheorem{afnSpace}{Definition}[section]
%Several Definitions which would be numbered sequentially, no issue with these, formatted the same as the line below
\newtheorem{frameDef}[afnSpace]{Definition} %Actually 5th definition
\newtheorem{frameDef s1}{Definition}[frameDef]

\begin{afnSpace} Definition 2.1 content here \end{afnSpace}
%Ommitted several definition environments that work fine
\begin{frameDef} Definition 2.5 content here \end{frameDef}
\begin{frameDef s1} Definition 2.5.1 content here \end{frameDef s1}
```

The issue here is that on my Ubuntu machine running via texLive, this compiles correctly, though with warning errors about undefined counters; however my supervisor is unable to get this to compile using MikTex.

I know that the solution is to be more explicit with counter creation, as I think that my definitions don't create their own counters, however I don't know how to rectify this. This is amy first ever document created with LaTeX and I don't know quite how it's counter system works.

Any help would be most appreciated,

Regards,
Jake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code compiles fine with MiKTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtheorem{afnSpace}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{frameDef}[afnSpace]{Definition} %Actually 5th definition
\newtheorem{frameDef s1}{Definition}[afnSpace]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\section{Affine Systems} %section 2 of the document
%Several Definitions which would be numbered sequentially, no issue with these, formatted the same as the line below
\begin{afnSpace} Definition 2.1 content here \end{afnSpace}
%Omitted several definition environments that work fine
\setcounter{afnSpace}{4}
\begin{frameDef} Definition 2.5 content here \end{frameDef}
\begin{frameDef s1} Definition 2.5.1 content here \end{frameDef s1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't belive that a simple code work for texlive and doesn't for miktex

Comment: @touhami: I slighly modified it: changed `[frameDef]` to `[afnSpace]` in the code for `frameDef s1`, to have no complaining about undefined counters, that's all.

Comment: My first comment was for every body and for the OP in particular. Now: your code does not work for me (no counter afnspace)

Comment: @touhami: it is `afnSpace`. Sorry, I forgot to move the declaration of `afnSpace` new theorem in the preamble. It's corrected now. Thanks for pointing the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this compiles without any error complaints on my machine now so hopefully won't give any on my tutors.